# How to start Nancy web server in c# (wpf)

Tags: c#, webserver, nancy

I'm trying to start a simple Nancy web server (In a WPF project as I need to have some windows as well...) using this code :

```
public class ProfilePage : NancyModule
{
    public ProfilePage()
    {
        var host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:8080"), new Bootstrapper());
        host.Start();

        Get("/", _ => { return $"Hello world"; });
    }

    public class SelfHostRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
    {

         public string GetRootPath()
         {
             return Environment.CurrentDirectory;
         }
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider
    {
        get { return new SelfHostRootPathProvider(); }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it just loads forever and eventually crashes with the following exception : System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Does someone know what have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you running from VS?  VS does not automatically run with ADMIN privilege's.  Start VS by right click shortcut and select RunAsAdmin.

Comment: I started Visual Studio as an administrator. However, it still doesn't work

Comment: Does someone know why doesn't it work?

Comment: If you debug it in VS, the call stack should tell you what's wrong. BTW, Nancy is no longer maintained, so you should try to avoid it. Migrate to .NET Core so that you can use ASP.NET Core + WPF together.

Comment: A web server should never access resource on the local machine.  Connections from client default to GUEST privilege's.  Running a service As Admin is also not recommended since you can open a back door to allow hackers access to the machine.  You should limit the amount of code run with Admin.  if you need access to files put them on a Network drive that allows guest to access the data.  I would check the Event Viewer on Windows to see if there are any errors associated with your application.

Comment: Why are you declaring the get after you've started the host? I normally do it the other way around.

Comment: @PalleDue I have moved the Get line before the host, it doesn't change anything?
If you normally do it, does my code looks fine to you?
I don't understand what I have done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NancyModule should only set up the routes and nothing else. There is also no need to reference the NancyModule in anyway, since it is picked up automatically by the bootstrapper. Something like this should suffice:

```cs
public class ProfilePage : NancyModule
{
    public ProfilePage()
    {
        Get("/", _ => { return $"Hello world"; });
    }
}
```

And then somewhere else, where you need to start your hosting:

```cs
using (var host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:8080")))
{
   host.Start();
   Console.WriteLine("Running on http://localhost:1234");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I think the problem you are seeing is that the host is starting, then trying to set up the routes, which starts by starting the host, which requires setting up the routes, which....
It's easy to see how it leads to StackOverflowException.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, now I have another exception : Nancy.Bootstrapper.MultipleRootPathProvidersLocatedException: 'More than one IRootPathProvider was found, and since we do not know which one you want to use, you need to override the RootPathProvider property on your bootstrapper and specify which one to use. Sorry for the inconvenience.'